# Program generates an error saying my method is not applicable for my arguments

Tags: java

I have the following piece of code that I've been looking at for a while now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumExercise {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input start value");
        int start = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input end value");
        int end = scanner.nextInt();
        int sum = computeSum(start,end);
        System.out.println("Sum is of integers from "+start+" to "+
        end+" is "+sum);
        scanner.close();
    }
    public static void computeSum() {
        for(int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
}
```

The way the program is supposed to work is that a user inputs a start value (`int start = scanner.nextInt();`) and then afterwards an end value (`int end = scanner.nextInt();`) and then the program will calculate the total sum (`int sum = computeSum(start,end);`).

So if the user inputs 4 as the start value and 8 as the end value, the program will calculate "4+5+6+7+8" and then assign the value "30" to the variable `sum`.

My exercise is to try and write the method `computeSum`.

My attempt at solving this has been to try and write a loop that increases with 1 integer where it starts with the variable `start` and ends with the variable `end`:

```
public static void computeSum() {
        for(int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
}
```

However it doesn't seem like I can get it to "link" with the `computeSum(start,end)`. Is there something that I'm missing? My program is saying that the arguments are not applicable but I'm not sure what it means by that. I'm sorry, I'm quite new to programming.

Comment: Well, yeah. You trying to pass parameters to your method, but your method doesn't take any parameters `public static void computeSum(//paramsShouldGoHere) {`. You are also expecting the computeSum() to return something, which it doesn't either because of `void`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `computeSum` to accept `start` and `end`, and since you assign the result of computing the sum it should `return` an `int` (`sum`). Like,

```
public static int computeSum(int start, int end) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**or**, in Java 8+, use a lambda. Like,

```
public static int computeSum(int start, int end) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end).sum();
}
```

**or**, apply Gauss's formula for summing natural numbers like

```
public static int computeSum(int start, int end) {
    return sumN(end) - sumN(start);
}

private static int sumN(int n) {
    return ((n + 2) * (n + 1)) / 2;
}
```

Comment: I actually did try to write 'computeSum(int, int)' before but it still generated an error and I thought that was just completely wrong! Thank you for your help. Can you explain to me why the "return sum;" is needed?

Comment: Because the method is set to return the sum, since it has `int` before the method name, and not `void` (second part of the first sentence of the answer). Hence, `return sum;`.

Comment: Because `int sum = computeSum(start,end);` implies you expect the method to *`return`* an `int`. And before you ask, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: Thank you both for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with `start`, you cant assign it to `i` and same goes for `sum` and `end`.
You need to make them global variables so both of the functions will recognize them